# Ninject Dependency injection in dotnet web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to implement dependency injection in web api 2 but unable to do so. Getting object reference not set error. 
Here is my implementatoin

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    .....
}
```

Interface:

```
 public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
    .....
}
```

Interface Implementation:

```
public class ProductRespository : IProductRepository, IDisposable
{
    private ApiContext _context;

    public ProductRespository(ApiContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    } 
    public ProductRespository()
    {

    } 
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Products.OrderBy(o => o.Name);
    }
   ......
}
```

And Ninjectwebcommon.cs class:

```
 public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start(){....}
    .....
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //kernel.Bind<IRepo>().ToMethod(ctx => new Repo("Ninject Rocks!"));
        kernel.Bind<ApiContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRespository>().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

And finally in my controller ProductController:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    private IProductRepository _productRepository = null;
    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public ProductController()
    {

    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts()
    {
        return Ok(_productRepository.GetAll());
    }
}
```

When getallproducts controller method is hit i get this exception

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Remove the default constructor of `ProductController` and try again. Note that your application components should only have one constructor.

Comment: Removing the default constructor will throw an error "no parameter less constructor found"

Comment: That means that Ninject isn't used to resolve MVC controllers _at all_. This is because you only set Web API's `DependencyResolver`, but not MVC's `DependencyResolver`. In MVC the calls look as follows: `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...);`.

Comment: You can find more about how to set up an MVC application with Ninject [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to your interface in ProductController. 
Try like this:

```
public IProductRepository _productRepository { get; set; }
```

I had the same problems, but using given codeline helped me / us out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724068/dependency-injection-fails-with-mvc5-and-ninject

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001124/web-api2-ninjectwebcommon-cs-do-not-appear/47002329#47002329

helped me out when I encountered that error. Maybe you find them helpful, too..